# Is it possible to use np.fft.fft to pick out the Fourier coefficients from one timepoint, at a specific frequency?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I am a first time stack exchange user and undergraduate students working on signal processing of sEEG signals using np.fft.fft.

I am trying to apply np.fft.fft on a 2D array of data of shape (98, 1024), where 98 is the number of trials and 1024 is the sampling rate in Hz. I am trying to find to get the Fourier coefficients at 500 milliseconds (corresponds to the 512th sample) at a frequency of 10Hz. But in my understanding np.ftt.ftt returns an array of shape (98, 1024) where 98 is once again the number of trials and 1024 is now the frequencies.
So if I'm interested in 10Hz, I can write this code: (correct me if my understanding is wrong)

```
after_fft = np.fft.fft(timeSeries, axis=1)
frequency_of_interest = after_fft[:, 10]
```

But how can I also keep track of the time information?

1. I adapted some code I found online (https://github.com/emma-holmes/Phase-Coherence-for-Python/blob/master/PhaseCoherence.py) to include another parameter for timePoint, but I realized there is no where to put the timePoint parameter.
2. I tried reducing the input to just the 512th sample to represent the 500 ms I'm interested in by doing data = data[:,511, np.newaxis] and passing that into the function below. However, for a given time, the output for the function (PC) did not vary with frequency, so this approach did not work either.
3. I looked for functions in python that return a 3D array with dimensions representing (number of trials, timepoints, frequencies).In this case, I could use the timePoint to index into after_fft, and then index into the specific frequency of interest.

Here is the code below with some print statments I added to understand the data structures better.
Thank you so much for your help!

```
def PhaseCoherenceGivenTime(freq, timeSeries, FS, timePoint=None):
    # Get parameters of input data
    nMeasures = np.shape(timeSeries)[0]
    nSamples = np.shape(timeSeries)[1]
    nSecs = nSamples / FS
    print('Number of measurements =', nMeasures)
    print('Number of time samples =', nSamples, '=', nSecs, 'seconds')

    # Calculate FFT for each measurement (spect is freq x measurements)
    spect = np.fft.fft(timeSeries, axis=1)
    print("Spect.shape: ", spect.shape)

    # Normalise by amplitude
    spect = spect / abs(spect)

    # Find spectrum values for frequency bin of interest
    freqRes = 1 / nSecs
    foibin = round(freq / freqRes + 1) - 1
    print('Foibin =', foibin)
    spectFoi = spect[:, foibin]
    print("spectFoi: ", spectFoi)
    print("spectFoi.shape: ", spectFoi.shape)

    # Find individual phase angles per measurement at frequency of interest
    anglesFoi = np.arctan2(spectFoi.imag, spectFoi.real)

    # PC is the root mean square of the sums of the cosines and sines of the angles
    PC = np.sqrt((np.sum(np.cos(anglesFoi)))**2 + (np.sum(np.sin(anglesFoi)))**2) / np.shape(anglesFoi)[0]

    # Print the value
    print('----------------------------------')
    print('Phase coherence value = ' + str("{0:.3f}".format(PC)))

    return anglesFoi, PC
```

Comment: If you are sampling at 1024 Hz, then, each sample covers approx 1ms. So .5 ms is not the 512th sample. Unless I miss what you meant by that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant .5 secs. Will modify my question

Comment: You cannot compute the frequency decomposition for one time point alone. Frequency is something you can observe only over time. So you need to take some window around your desired time point. The longer the window, the more precise the frequency decomposition is.

Comment: If you want to compute the DFT for a single frequency, don’t use the FFT. The FFT is an algorithm to get the full DFT cheaply. But if you are only interested in one single frequency, just directly compute [the DFT sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) for that frequency, it’ll be a lot cheaper.

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks so much for the feedback! i agree with your first comment-- conceptually I was thinking that you can't compute the frequency decomposition for one time point alone. However, I have seen some tutorials on the internet that do so. For example this one-- https://www.mattcraddock.com/blog/2020/06/12/what-is-intertrial-coherence/ he "pick[s] out the Fourier coefficients from one timepoint, approximately 178 ms after stimulus onset, at 10 Hz." How is this possible conceptually? This was using R code, a toolbox that is only available in R-- is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Also, I saw this visualization (linked below) where the phase is computed for the time only, and frequency is not considered. Is there a way to just consider time then? So the phases at a given time (in this example t = 0) irrespective of frequencies? https://twitter.com/nschawor/status/1207063815830921222?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1207063815830921222%7Ctwgr%5Ead0228db25873e2181ebbf4f2a31af196f46917d%7Ctwcon%5Es1_c10&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mattcraddock.com%2Fblog%2F2020%2F06%2F12%2Fwhat-is-intertrial-coherence%2F

Comment: Yeah, they’re using a window around the point. Look up “window function” (you can’t just cut out a section of the signal, you need to taper at the edges.

Comment: take a look at [Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html). It might be what you want